# Only one Print Task may be created when the Print Task Requested event is raised. Any other solution for this create print task one more

Tags: c#, uwp

Only one Print Task may be created when the Print Task Requested event is raised. Any other solution for this create print task one more in Print Task Requested event like created print task remove and again create or any other solution for this

Any suggestion?

Comment: We're going to need some more information.  Please post some code as well as what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly stated in the UWP [documentation on printing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app#register-for-printing):

> If one screen of your app has registered for printing, it must unregister for printing when it exits. If it is replaced by another screen, the next screen must register for a new Print contract when it opens.

Currently, only one print task can exist at the same time (it will start a print window, this window is the only one). So you cannot create multiple print tasks at the same time.

But you can create multiple pages in one print task. Regarding this, you can check the following:

- [Print from your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app)
- [Printing sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing)